# Convert a time string "20180425.142117" to human readable format?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, datetime-conversion

I want this string "20180425.142117" to convert to human readable format. 
E.g. 25th April 2018, 2:21 pm in Python

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What representation is that? Have you tried googling?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime("20180425.142117", "%Y%m%d.%H%M%S").ctime()`  -- See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) library.

```
import datetime as dt
time_str = "20180425.142117"
# Convert to a datetime 
time_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y%m%d.%H%M%S')
# Convert back to string with the right format
human_time = dt.datetime.strftime(time_dt, '%dth %b %Y, %I:%M%p')
print(human_time)
```

I have to say that I look up the codes each time I need to do something custom.